UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training when training VGG-16 in jupyternotebook
When i train my vgg16 model in jupyter notebook in even epoch th training interuppted because ran ot of data the error
UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least steps_per_epoch * epochs batches. You may need to use the .repeat() function when building your dataset.
Below is code for my data set
batch_size = 25
trdata = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                                         zoom_range=0,
                                                         rotation_range=0)
traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory(directory="RipSetCocoaCNCH12/train",
                                         target_size=(224, 224),
                                         class_mode="categorical",
                                         batch_size=batch_size,
                                         interpolation='nearest'
                                         )
tsdata = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                                         zoom_range=0,
                                                         rotation_range=00)
testdata = tsdata.flow_from_directory(directory="RipSetCocoaCNCH12/test",
                                         target_size=(224, 224),
                                         class_mode="categorical",
                                         batch_size=batch_size,
                                         interpolation='nearest'
                                         )

Found 2800 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 1200 images belonging to 4 classes.
so for step_per_epoch i set it 2800/25 but when i run it in odd epoch the training interuppted because ran out of data so the result are like this
Accuracy
so anyone know why i ran out of data?
%%time
hist = model.fit(x=traindata,
                 steps_per_epoch=traindata.samples // batch_size,
                 validation_data= testdata,
                 validation_steps=testdata.samples // batch_size,
                 epochs=10,
                 callbacks=None)


The issue you facing  where your data generator is not able to produce enough batches to match the specified number of steps per epoch.Try adjusting the batch size to a value that evenly divides the number of samples in your dataset. For example, if you have 2800 training images and you want to use a batch size of 25, you could try changing the batch size to 20 or 28.As the warning suggests, you may need to use the .repeat() function when building your dataset.
